# showing JSON parser listview on android

Tags: android, json

In my server , showing text this.

`[{"name":"AAA", "age":"1"},
 {"name":"BBB", "age":"2"},
 {"name":"CCC", "age":"3"}]`

and I want see this text my phone.

so, I use asynctask on android

```
    String strData = "";

.
.
.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  //result = show server text
   super.onPostExecute(result);

   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
   try {
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            strData += object.getString("name")
                    +  object.getInt("age");

            adapter.add(strData);
       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

this result my phone

```
AAA 1
----------------
AAA 1
BBB 2
----------------
```

but I want show

```
AAA 1
-----------
BBB 2
```

this.

perhaps, `for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {` here problem?

please advice for me 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so easy, see this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        strData += object.getString("name")
                +  object.getInt("age");

        adapter.add(strData);
        strData = "";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String strData = object.getString("name")
                    +  object.getInt("age");

            adapter.add(strData);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its better to use GSON. Anyway here your issue is str date is declared global. So kindly put  String strData = ""; inside Forloop in post execute or

```
>  @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  //result = show server text    
     super.onPostExecute(result);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            strData="";
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            strData += object.getString("name")
                    +  object.getInt("age");
            adapter.add(strData);
        }   
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);    }
```